# Function getUi not found in object Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I'm trying to create a function that's trigerred when its container-bound Form is submited, then retrieves some cells from a spreadsheet and display them to the Form's user in an alert window.

Here's the code :

```
function displayResult() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
var range = sheet.getRange("BI" + lastrow + ":BM" + lastrow);
var values = range.getValues();
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ui = form.getUi();
ui.alert('values[0][0]');
}
```

Nothing happens on Form submission and I'm getting the following error message :

> TypeError: Function getUi not found in object Form. at
>   displayResult(Code:7)

Comment: There is no `getUi()` method of the Form class.  You can use `var ui = FormApp.getUi()`  See documentation:  [Link - getUi](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getui)

Comment: When you open up a spreadsheet with a script there is no user interface because the spreadsheet has opened up on the server and there is no user.

Comment: @SandyGood , I tried with `var ui = FormApp.getUi()` but it's not working. It gives me the following error : 
"Cannot call FormApp.getUi() from this context."

@Cooper I don't want to open and modify Spreadsheet's UI, I want to do this on the current opened/submitted Form

Comment: Custom dialogs do not work on a Google Form except when the Form is in Edit mode.

Comment: Yeah indeed, saw that in the doc link you pasted here. Thanks for your help, I guess my problem is unsolvable then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsolvable problem : As Sandy Good said, custom dialogs do not work on a Google Form except when the Form is in Edit mode.