# How to dynamically show HTML to Google Forms responder, based on their quiz answers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I'm creating a survey which evaluates the 'health' of a user based on their answers.

It's created as a quiz with 'golf-scoring', i.e. the lower the score the better their health, and it should display some graphical result at the end based on their final score (ideally a traffic light style diagram).

The question I'm stuck on is: *how to show some HTML to the user?* It seems like it should be a fairly straightforward task but I haven't been successful. I'm a developer so am comfortable using App Script, but then [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) makes it sound like there's **no way** to show dynamic content to the user.

We'll be sending an email to them and it seems like this is pretty customizable so I'm able to implement a nice diagram for that, but I'd also like to show this in the form.

Has anyone been successful in using App Script to show some custom UI to the user?

Comment: Custom Dialogs are html. You can use [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) to create graphical content in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for that link @Cooper - it's not the creation of HTML I'm struggling with, but how to show this to a user going through a Google Forms quiz. All the code examples I find only show custom UI within the Forms editor. Is there a way to show a popup/modal to a Google Forms responder?

Comment: No. You can't interact with the Google Forms programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to show a custom dialog to Google Forms respondents.

Related

- [Is it possible to display popup on google form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23866589/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script - Run javascript as the form is being filled by users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26977954/1595451)
- [Function getUi not found in object Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47944887/1595451)

Comment: Understood - the only way to dynamically set content with App Script is by creating new questions, or via the emails you send out to respondents?

Comment: You can create dynamic content with apps script but not with Google Forms.  You could build your own html based forms.

Comment: @Rhys You could use Google Apps Script to modify a form in several ways but that is not "dynamic". Also you could use it to send emails. The email could be dynamic as far as the email client used by your users support it.

Comment: It's probably not worth the effort to recreate the entire form with HTML (it's many pages and questions). Thanks both for the clarifications :)